# Images not loading on heroku hosted site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, rails-activestorage

I built out a ruby on rails backend/react frontend/ postgres database. This app is using AWS/S3 storage for photos and is being hosted on heroku. When running the site on local host 3000,the images are showing up just fine but on the heroku hosted site, the AWS images are left blank. This site was working fine over a year ago but since then, I had to update the rails version and some heroku subscriptions and a few other things to get it up and running again.

In the console, the img src is:

/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBHUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--eaab6e20c967f635644a51cb7033ae93eaf6e7c6/calathea4.JPG

Here is the link to the current heroku site: https://plantsy-etsy.herokuapp.com/

If anyone knows more about AWS, rails, or active storage blobs and could lead me in any direction to figure out why these images are not working on my heroku hosted site, that would be great!

I've attached screenshots for reference:
[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLGqY.png)
[img src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GL6o.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you check if those images were actually uploaded to your AWS s3 bucket? If so, check the file & bucket permissions to make sure they are "public".

Comment: @Unixmonkey yes, the S3 bucket has all images uploaded and is set to public. Again, images are working fine on local host but not on heroku app